# Mixing casted pointers and reference

Tags: c++

I have code:

```
Widget& Widget::GetWidget() const {
    auto pWidget = dynamic_cast<Widget*>(pBaseWidget);
    assert(pWidget != nullptr);
    return *pWidget;
}
```

`_pBaseWidget` is a type `BaseWidget*` which `Widget` is derived from.

`_pBaseWidget` is valid outside of this scope. The code works fine and behaves as expected.

However, I find it odd returning a reference to some data a casted local pointer was pointing to.

Is it safe to mix casted pointers and reference here?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you find odd about this. There's nothing wrong with this, whatsoever (presuming that all the claimed constraints hold true), but if you were to extrapolate about exactly what seems "odd" to you, this might be something worth clarifying here.

Comment: Assuming `pWidget` is not `nullptr`: why do you think, that this is unsafe?

Comment: Aside: you mustn't prefix variable names with `_`.

Comment: [dynamic_cast conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) may help.

Comment: @PaulEvans there's no such rule.

Comment: A local pointer or a derivative thereof is OK to return. A pointer to local data is not.

Comment: *"`_pBaseWidget` is a type `BaseWidget`"* - I hope you mean it is of type `BaseWidget*`, otherwise, the code would not compile that dynamic cast. And fyi, regardless of answers below this code is inherently dangerous. `assert` compiles to a no-op in release-builds, Therefore a release-build with a failed dynamic cast would result a null `pWidget` and `return *pWidget;` invokes *undefined behavior*. IMHO, you're better off with `Widget*` and returning the result of the dynamic cast. If the cast fails, `nullptr` is returned and the caller can detect this and take appropriate action.

Comment: @eerorika yes there is: "Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace."

Comment: @PaulEvans *"you mustn't prefix variable names"*  is different from *"... in the global namespace"*. There can be variables in scopes other than the global napespace, and the actual rule that you quoted doesn't apply to those variables.

Comment: @eerorika but if there's a global variable `_pBaseWidget`, and you also make that one of your class variables, there's a clash whenever you use `_pBaseWidget` without scope qualification as in the OP.

Comment: @PaulEvans There is no clash because of the name hiding feature. The implementation defined global would be safely hidden in the scope of a member function and usage would refer to the member variable as intended. If the global is a documented one, then it can be accessed with a fully qualified name if necessary.

Comment: @eerorika Interesting, so *mustn't* isn't appropriate. I'd still want to steer clear of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it safe to mix casted pointers and reference here?

There is nothing inherently "unsafe" about mixing references and pointers.

Presumably, `_pBaseWidget` is a pointer. If it is a pointer, then it cannot be dynamically casted into a reference. But the author of the function wants to (or needs to) return a reference, so they indirect through the pointer.

> However, I find it odd returning a reference to ...

Returning a reference is often preferable to returning a pointer. It absolves the caller from the responsibility of checking whether the returned pointer is null.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe (insofar as anything using raw pointers is safe).

You are simply returning a reference to whatever `_pbaseWidget` points to, having first verified that it actually points to a `Widget`.  The reference returned remains valid until whatever `_pbaseWidget` points to goes out of scope.